# Multiple Instance with GetX tag not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, multiple-instances

Ive been working on a multiple instance project. so i tried doing this in the counter app.
but only first instance is updating. below is my all code.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  InstanceModel selected = InstanceModel.instances.first;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                  ),
                  Expanded(child: Container()),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: ListView.separated(
                        itemCount: InstanceModel.instances.length,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        separatorBuilder: (c, i) => const SizedBox(
                              width: 50,
                            ),
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          final InstanceModel instance =
                              InstanceModel.instances[i];
                          final isSelected = selected == instance;
                          return SizedBox(
                            width: 80,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                selected = instance;
                                setState(() {});
                              },
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor:
                                    isSelected ? Colors.green : Colors.black,
                              ),
                              child: Text(instance.name),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          const Text(
            'You have pushed the button this many times:',
          ),
          GetBuilder<InstanceController>(
              tag: selected.name,
              builder: (_) {
                return Text(
                  '${selected.controller.count}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                );
              }),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          selected.controller.increment();
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Model class

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:train/instance_controller.dart';

class InstanceModel {
  final InstanceController controller;
  final String name;

  InstanceModel({
    required this.controller,
    required this.name,
  });

  static List<InstanceModel> instances = [
    InstanceModel(
        name: "1",
        controller:
            Get.put<InstanceController>(InstanceController(), tag: "1")),
    InstanceModel(
        name: "2",
        controller:
            Get.put<InstanceController>(InstanceController(), tag: "2")),
  ];
}
```

and controller class

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class InstanceController extends GetxController {
  var count = 0.obs;

  void increment() {
    count++;
    update();
  }
}
```

only calling setstate is updating the second instance. i dont understand where im wrong.
any help will be appreciated---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really was confused at first that this might be some bug since logically your code is right, then I noticed that this about Flutter widgets replacing each by other on new state rather than completely removing that widget then adding it again in the widget tree.

on update state ( `setState(() {})` ), flutter searches first for widgets with the same type to replace each with other, in this situation, when you're expecting that `GetBuilder` should trigger state for each separated unique controllers, flutter just update one with the other with saving it's state.

And to fix it, you should simply add a `Key` to the `GetBuilder` to tell flutter that each of it is unique like this:

```
  GetBuilder<InstanceController>(
          key: UniqueKey(), // add this
          tag: selected.name,
          builder: (_) {
            return Text(
              '${selected.controller.count}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            );
          }),
```

Comment: Thanks man!! great observation.  i also thought it was a bug from getx.  thanks again